# Open graph: What is this called & How to generate it?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api

Can anyone tell me how is this generated? ref. i've seen Guardian/WashingtonPOST creating these feed group on my facebook feed.

Feed Activity group: 
https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/377098_2775596322548_1637306992_2452717_982129282_n.jpg

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to [Facebook's developer's section](http://developers.facebook.com/) you will see a few handy "easy to use" plugins for your website... if those don't fit the bill for you, they provide a [JSON based Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Comment: Isn't this generated by application itself through graph api ? though i have already checked the plugins but couldn't figure out what exactly this is, any specific reference will be helpful.